# Graphs: Prove that you can select dresses in a way that all colors are contained

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

A producer uses 16 different colors in producing dresses. 2 different colors are used in each dress. If no 2 dresses are used with same colors and each color is used in at least 8 dresses, Prove that you can select 8 dresses than contain all 16 colors.

Any hints how to start the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us use the graph with vertices corresponding to colors and edges corresponding to dresses. So two vertices are adjacent if and only if there is a dress with two colors corresponding to these vertices. Then we have $|G| = 16$ and $\deg v \ge 8$ for all $v \in V(G)$. And we should prove that $G$ has a [perfect matching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html).

By [Dirac's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiracsTheorem.html) we have that $G$ is Hamiltonian. Also its order is even. Therefore it has at least two perfect matchings. (We can take every second edge of a Hamiltonian cycle to get the first perfect matching and all other edges of the same cycle to get the second perfect matching.)